# Is it better to dereference a pointer to get a value or create a local object and access the value that way?

Tags: c++, performance, pointers

For example say I am looping through a vector of pointers to check multiple objects and perform operations on them. I could do either of the following.

Method 1:

```
std::vector< Object* >::iterator it;
Object* o;
for (it = objects.begin(); it != objects.end(); ++it)
{
    o = (*it)
    if(o->GetActive())
    {
        o->method;
        o->method2;
        o->method3;
        //etc...
    }
 }
```

Method 2:

```
std::vector< Object* >::iterator it;
for (it = objects.begin(); it != objects.end(); ++it)
{
    if((*it)->GetActive())
    {
        (*it)->method;
        (*it)->method2;
        (*it)->method3;
        //etc...
    }
 }
```

From what I can see Method 1 has easier readability as dereferencing syntax can often complicate the readability, especially when you are doing something like:

```
if((*o)->CheckValue((*c)))
```

But creating local variables would make it much easier to read:

```
if(o->CheckValue(c))
```

But you are creating extra variables which would increase the memory cost, right?

What would the differences in performance be?

Comment: *What would the differences in performance be?*  Negligible at worst, or non-existent at best.  The compiler will deal with this for you.  You should concern yourself with writing legible code.  Option 1 will be fine.  Create local variables to store values for clarity.

Comment: If you're going to do the first one, move `Object *o = (*it);` into the for-loop. Practice as-local-as-possible for your vars.

Comment: Your local variable would hardly affect memory.  You are allocating it on the stack, and it will be removed when the function exits. Unless you are writing code for embedded software of some kind with strict constraints, today's compilers are highly efficient, so I don't think it would matter.

Comment: @OldProgrammer: even better, it's almost sure that `o` will be put in a register.

Comment: "*But you are creating extra variables which would increase the memory cost, right?*" Who cares? It's not 1990 anymore. Write clean, clear, maintainable code.

Comment: I always thought that having the value declared outside the loop would increase performance. I guess the compiler probably takes care of this as well? I had no idea the compiler would do such things before.

Comment: @enr4ged: Modern compilers probably don't care anymore, but it used to be a performance _decrease_. By allocating it at a larger scope, you told the compiler to keep the variable allocated longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An optimizing compiler will *probably* make them the same. Sometimes it's nice to assign to a variable for better readability. If the container didn't contain pointers you could use a reference instead:

```
std::vector< Object >::iterator it;
for (it = objects.begin(); it != objects.end(); ++it)
{
    const Object &o = (*it)
    if(o.GetActive())
    {
        o.method();
        o.method2();
        o.method3();
        //etc...
    }
 }
```

Edit: As Raymond points out in the comments, the compiler can't make certain optimizations if the methods might mutate the object in question. The way to fix that is to use `const` when possible, so I've changed my example to show it in practice. If you do this you can't call methods on the object that aren't also marked `const`.

Comment: They are not equivalent if `objects` might change value during the call to one of the methods. The optimizer may not have insight into this at compile time and will therefore have to be conservative.

Comment: @RaymondChen: It's implicit that `objects` does not change. Doing so might invalidate `it`, if a reallocation would be needed. In this particular case, it would also invalidate `Object* o`. For such modifying loops, you should use an index instead, and use `index < vector.size()` as the loop condition.

Comment: @MSalters: that's what I initially thought, but aren't iterators allowed to be invalidated only when the vector changes size?

Comment: @MSalters Not all operations invalidate iterators. (Otherwise, `for_each` would rarely work!) For example, if one of the methods does `objects[0] = new Object()`, this will change the object accessed by the iterator without invalidating it. The original capturing version would operate on the old object. (This answer's reference version is equivalent though.) Note also that `objects` is a vector of `Object*` not `Object`, so the capture needs to be `const Object *o = *it` and then the method calls `o->method()` etc.

Comment: @MarkRansom Note that the `const` here doesn't help because `objects` itself might change. The `const` is saying that the pointed-to object cannot change through `o`, but that doesn't prevent the pointed-to object from changing by other means.

Comment: @RaymondChen, yes it became obvious to me that I had misread your comment after I saw some of the other comments. It should be unusual for an object method to affect the container that the object is contained in - but I should know better since I deal with such code daily.

Comment: @MarkRansom It's less unusual for a method to do something like DoEvents, at which point the ambient framework can run unrelated code that replaces items in the collection. This is the sort of scary thing that can be very difficult to debug because it relies on timing.

Comment: Ow, misunderstanding, you can indeed replace the pointer in the container and that will affect the cached copy.

Answer (score 1):

I would in fact choose another syntax, which makes the choice irrelevant:

```
for (Object* o : objects)
{
  // ... body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have `volatile` objects around, when dealing with local objects it mostly comes down just to readability, since compilers routinely deal with this stuff by themselves.

In your particular case, `*it` is an operation that the compiler *has* to perform, and whose result will end in a register; so, it's almost sure that the compiler will leave the result in the register anyway for the next uses, thus "implicitly" creating your `o` variable. In other words, coming down to assembly that variable arises by itself.

It's a different situation, instead, if the compiler cannot trivially prove that `it` is not modified between dereferentiations (e.g. if a pointer to it - or to `objects` - is passed around, or if it's nonlocal) or if it's explicitly instructed to avoid this kind of optimizations (via the `volatile` keyword).